# Finding parameters that give constrained eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I want to obtain the eigenvalues $x_1,x_2,x_3$ of a hermitian, off-diagonal matrix,

`{{0, Conjugate[d], Conjugate[g]}, {d, 0, Conjugate[h]}, {g, h, 0}}`,

under the condition/assumption that the eigenvalues fulfil

$x_1^2-x_2^2=0.2\:$ and $\:x_2^2-x_3^2=0.3\:$.

How can I do that in Mathematica?

Comment: But, how do you decided which one is $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$?

Comment: @march - they would have the order `Abs[x1] > Abs[x2] > Abs[x3]`

Comment: Here's how I think it should go, but I can't get it to return an answer `evals = Eigenvalues[{{0, Conjugate[d], Conjugate[g]}, {d, 0, 
    Conjugate[h]}, {g, h, 0}}];FindInstance[{0.3, 0.2} == 
  Differences@Sort[(evals /. {d -> dd, h -> hh, g -> gg})^2], {dd, hh,
   gg}]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't stop running, as you said.